# Image simulation with GNU Parallel on multiple nodes on HPC cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu, hpc, slurm

For my research I'm doing image simulations using third party software, which I am running on the high performance computing cluster of our university.

The input arguments of the software are the begin and end (x,y)-coordinates of the part to be simulated. This allows me to simulate just 1 pixel at (x,y), or for example small clusters of NxN pixels. The image sizes I am simulating are at most 256x256 pixels.

For every call, the software has to load the same four files that define the 'object' to be imaged. These file are about 500 Mb each. The calculation take about 10 seconds for one pixel, and finally are written to a shared output file.

To summarize, the software has the following workflow for each call:

1. Load 'object' files
2. Initiate calculation
3. Calculate intensity for desired pixel(s)
4. Write intensity to shared output file at the correct location

I run these serial jobs in parallel using GNU parallel with the SLURM workload manager. When I start this job, several nodes on the HPC are reserved. However, I observe that the CPU usage decays seriously when I claim more and more cores. When I take a look at the output of the '--progress' call of GNU parallel, I see that only one node is busy. So I expect that despite reserving multiple nodes, only one node is running.

How can I make sure the jobs are actually distributed over the reserved nodes?

The code is as follows:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=200
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1

...

# Image size
SIZE=256

# NBLOCKxNBLOCK cluster size
NBLOCK=2

# Number of clusters in image
N=$((${SIZE}/${NBLOCK}))

# Most right pixel                                           
MAXPIXEL=$(((${N}-1)*${NBLOCK})) 

# Array of start coordinates                                       
BEGIN=$(seq 0 ${NBLOCK} ${MAXPIXEL}) 

# Array of end coordinates                                   
END=$(seq $((${NBLOCK}-1)) ${NBLOCK} $((${MAXPIXEL}+${NBLOCK}-1)))      

parallel --progress -j 100% --delay 1 --joblog data/logs/runtask.log --resume srun --exclusive -N1 -n1 [relevant software call here] ::: ${BEGIN} :::+ ${END} ::: ${BEGIN} :::+ ${END}
```

Comment: Can you try `-j 200` instead of `-j 100%`?

Comment: I also have tried this since I used -j ${SLURM_NTASKS} before, but this does not improve the result. For 20 cores the maximum efficiency I get is about 50-70%, but for 200 cores the efficiency is 5-15%. Yesterday I tried to use --sshloginfile with the nodelist, and then the --progress output indeed shows the multiple nodes. Nevertheless the efficiency is still very poor.